# Why does this derivation of exponential growth give a different, but apparently not wrong, answer?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

Here's a fairly standard derivation of the exponential growth equation.

$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = kx$

$\int\frac{1}{x}\text{d}x = \int k\text{d}t$

$ln(x)=kt+C$

$x=C'\text{e}^{kt}$

Right?

But what if I don't separate my variables in step 2? I don't *have* to.

$\int \text{d}x = \int kx \text{d}t$

$x = kxt + C$

$(1-kt)x = C$

$x = \frac{C}{1-kt}$

Nothing like the same result! They can't both be correct, but each step looks sound to me. What's the error?

Comment: $x$ isn't constant with respect to $t$. So, $\int kx\,dt\ne kxt+C$.

Comment: Think of $x$ as a function $x(t)$ as @DavidMitra hints

Comment: But we allow this with partial derivatives, don't we? What's the difference?